# CloudKit Bad Request on Users Record Update with Web Services API

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services, cloudkit-js

I added a custom field to the default `Users` record type in CloudKit, and I'm trying to push a value to that new field.

Here's how my request is structured in Node JS:

```
var query = {
  operations :[{
    operationType: 'forceUpdate',
    record:{
      recordType: 'Users',
      fields:{
        myCustomField: { value: 'stuff' }
      },
      recordName: '_abc123'
    }
  }]
}
```

I'm getting this response from CloudKit:

```
records: [{
  recordName: '_abc123',
  reason: 'invalid id string, id=_abc123',
  serverErrorCode: 'BAD_REQUEST'
}]
```

If I put that same custom field on another, custom Record Type (like if I make my own `User` (without the "s") type) that also has `myCustomField` on it, the update works fine. So there must be something special I have to do to update the system `Users` type.

Does anyone know how to update a field on a `Users` record with the web services API?